# How to change alignment?

Tags: exam, alignment

I would like to move "Consider the possible triangle with...", the part above (b) to be aligned with the original question "In triangle PQR, ...". I tried \noindent but that doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question In triangle PQR, $\textrm{PR} = 12 \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm} \hspace{1mm}, \textrm{QR} = p \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm} \hspace{1mm}, \textrm{PQ} = r \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$ and $\textrm{Q} \hat{\textrm{P}} \textrm{R} = 30 \degree \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$

\vspace{\stretch{.05}}

\begin{parts}
\part Use the cosine rule to show that $r^{2} - 12 \sqrt{3} r + 144 - p^{2} = 0$

\vspace{\stretch{.5}}

\noindent
Consider the possible triangles with $\textrm{QR} = 8 \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$.

\vspace{\stretch{.05}}

\part Calculate the two corresponding values of $\textrm{PQ}$.

\vspace{\stretch{.5}}

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Thank you.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\uplevel`:

```
\uplevel{Consider the possible triangles with $\textrm{QR} = 8 \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$.}
```

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\special{papersize=8.5in,11in}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\setlength{\parskip}{1.5em}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question In triangle PQR, $\textrm{PR} = 12 \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm} \hspace{1mm}, \textrm{QR} = p \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm} \hspace{1mm}, \textrm{PQ} = r \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$ and $\textrm{Q} \hat{\textrm{P}} \textrm{R} = 30 \degree \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$

\vspace{\stretch{.05}}

\begin{parts}
\part Use the cosine rule to show that $r^{2} - 12 \sqrt{3} r + 144 - p^{2} = 0$

\vspace{\stretch{.5}}

\uplevel{Consider the possible triangles with $\textrm{QR} = 8 \hspace{1mm} \textrm{cm}$.}

\vspace{\stretch{.05}}

\part Calculate the two corresponding values of $\textrm{PQ}$.

\vspace{\stretch{.5}}

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```